# What is the current Solana daily emissions?

Tags: supply

Solana is inflationary, but what is the daily emissions rate? And is there a graph for this?

Comment: This is too specific. I'd suggest editing it to "How can I determine the current Solana daily power use?" It's impossible to know how validators get their electricity.

Comment: mikemaccana, I believe OP is asking about token emissions, not carbon emissions. But I could be wrong?

Comment: SOL token emissions obviously.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe what you're looking for is here:

https://docs.solana.com/inflation/inflation_schedule